# Avoid nesting promises with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, eslint

My aim is send verification email after signUp automatically.
I'm making this be Firebase function.

My code is at below.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(userCredential => {
            console.log(userCredential);

            Firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
            .then(() => {
                window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
                res.status(200).send(userCredential);
                res.status(200).send(userCredential);
                return;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
            });
            return;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(400).send(error);
})
```

But this handling is warned by lint.

If my aproach was invalid, please correct me.

And below is the screen of my code.
[image]

Comment: Could you post the entire code of your Cloud Function. It seems that you are trying to use the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method into an HTTP Cloud Function, which is not correct (it is not part of the Admin SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth). Can you explain your goal in more detail, in addition to posting the entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(userCredential => {
    console.log(userCredential);
    return Firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
  })
  .then(res => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
    res.status(200).send(userCredential);
    res.status(200).send(userCredential);
    return; 
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(400).send(error);
  })
```